# How to create PDF file from API Response on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning to make an application that captures the response api from the server and then I want to make the response from the api into a pdf file in flutter, are there any instructions or examples of how I should make it? thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the response that you get from the API into a PDF file using this package: [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Center(
          child: pw.Text(<API response>),
        ); 
      })); 

final file = File("example.pdf");
await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
```

Comment: Thanks sir, it work, but how if i want to make a download to pdf that create?coz its only view the result in pdf. thanks before.

Comment: To save the pdf in mobile storage, have a look at `To save the pdf file:` section within the package documentation (similar to the end of the snippet above). Also look at [reading-writing-files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)